# In the space $K(X)$ with the topology induced by the Hausdorff metric, $K_f(X)=\{K\in K(X): K\,\text{is finite}\}$ is $F_{\sigma}$.

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, set-theory, hausdorff-distance

**The Problem**: Let $X$ be metrizable, let $K(X)$ be the space of all compact subsets of $X$ with the topology induced by the Hausdorff metric $d_H$. Show that the set $K_f(X)=\{A\in K(X): K\,\text{is finite}\}$ is of the form $\underset{n\in\mathbb{N}}{\cup}F_n$, where $F_n$ are closed sets.

**Source**: *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by Alexander S. Kechris.

**My Attempt**: Let $\mathcal{A}_n=\{A\in K(X): |A|\leq n\}$. It suffices to show that each $\mathcal{A}_n$ is closed. To that end, fix $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and let $(A_i)$ be a sequence in $\mathcal{A}_n$ such that $(A_i)\to A$ for some $A\in K(X)$. We show that $A\in\mathcal{A}_n$. Note that $(A_i)\to A\iff d_H(A, A_i)\to0\iff\forall\epsilon>0\exists N\in\mathbb{N}\;\text{such that}\;i\geq N$ implies $\underset{x\in A}{\max}d(x, A_i)<\epsilon$ and $\underset{y\in A_i}{\max}d(y, A)<\epsilon$. Recall that $d(x, A_i)=\underset{y\in A_i}{\inf}d(x, y)$ and similarly $d(y, A)=\underset{x\in A}{\inf}d(y, x)$. Suppose, BWOC, that $|A|\geq n+1$. **Screeching halt**.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you replace some of those $K$'s by other letters, you use $K$ for pretty much everything and it is slightly confusing. Concerning the proof, can't you just assume that $\vert K \vert \geq n+1$, pick $(x_i)_{i=1}^{n+1}\in K$ ($n+1$ different points) and let $\ell=\min \{ d(x_i, x_i) \ : \ i,j \in \{ 1, \dots, n+1 \}, i \neq j \}$. Now, let $\varepsilon=\ell/4$. We have that $\vert B(x_i, \varepsilon)\cap K_j\vert \geq 1$, otherwise $d_H(x_i,K_j)>\varepsilon$. On the other hand, we know that $B(x_i, \varepsilon) \cap B(x_j, \varepsilon) = \emptyset$ for $i\neq j$.

Comment: Thus, every element of $K_j$ can be in at most one of the balls. However, there are $n+1$ balls and only $n$ elements in $K_j$, which yields the desired contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We argue by contradiction. Let $(K_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq \mathcal{K}_n$ that converges to $S\in K(X)$. Assume that $\vert S \vert\geq n+1$. Pick $n+1$ (pairwise different) points $(x_j)_{j=1}^{n+1}$ in $S$.

Furthermore, let $\ell = \min\{ d(x_i, x_j) \ : \ i,j\in \{1, \dots, n+1\}, i\neq j \}$ be the minimal distance between the points $(x_j)_{j=1}^{n+1}$ and choose $\varepsilon = \ell/4$.

Let $N_\varepsilon\in \mathbb{N}$, such that $d_H(S,K_j)<\varepsilon$ for all $j\geq N_\varepsilon$. As $d_H(x_i,K_j)\leq d(S,K_j) < \varepsilon$, we get that $\vert B(x_i,\varepsilon) \vert \geq 1$. On the other hand, two such balls cannot intersect, i.e. $B(x_j,\varepsilon) \cap B(x_m, \varepsilon) = \emptyset$ for all $j,m\in \{1, \dots, n+1\}$ with $j\neq m$. Indeed, assume that $x\in B(x_j,\varepsilon) \cap B(x_m, \varepsilon)$, then we have

\begin{align*}
 \ell < d(x_j, x_m) \leq d(x_j,x) + d(x,x_m) < \varepsilon + \varepsilon = \ell/2,
\end{align*}
which is a contradiction.

However, we have now $n+1$ balls that need to contain at least one point from $K_j$ and no point in $K_j$ can be in two ball simultaneously, thus $K_j$ contains at least $n+1$ points, which contradicts the assumption that $K_j\in \mathcal{K}_n$.

This proves that $S\in \mathcal{K}_n$ and hence $\mathcal{K}_n$ is a closed subset of $K(X)$. Therefore, we can write

$$ K_f(X) = \bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \mathcal{K}_n, $$

i.e. $K_f(X)$ is a countable union of closed sets in $K(X)$.

Comment: @Balajisb I am confused by your comment. The limit $S$ is by definition a compact set (otherwise $(K_j)_j$ would not converge to $S$ in $K(X)$).

Comment: Isnt the whole space Topology generated by sets in $K(X)$ w.r.t Hausdorff metric ? So $S$ the limit need not be closed ? But will be of the form $S = \cup_n F_n =  \lim \inf K_i = \cup_n \cap_{i \geq n} K_i$ if $S = \lim \inf_i K_i$. But this need not be true. Looks like little more argument needed to complete proof but you have definitely answered the attempt in his question as his attempt is about boundedness.

Comment: @Balajisb No, you are considering the space $K(X)$ that consists of all compact sets of $X$. We choose the Hausdorff metric to turn $K(X)$ into a metric space (it is easy to see that for more general sets the Hausdorff metric does not give you a metric, consider the distance of $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Euclidean metric). So, $S$ will always be a compact set in $X$ (as it is an element of $K(X)$ by definition). This whole thing proves that $\mathcal{A}_n$ (which was $\mathcal{K}_n$ before) is closed in $K(X)$.

Comment: @Balajisb I have added some lines in my answer that might help you to clear up the confusion.

Comment: Thanks ... i see..